# Docker selenium gird unable to connect our client URL

Tags: docker, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

We have a automation script which runs in jenkins and grid in docker.
So when ever we try to run the selenium code it connects to the grid node chrome or ff and then executes on the basis of the selenium java code.

All this happens in linux server where docker is installed and we have four container- Jenkins, Selenium grid, chrome node and ff node.

But when I am trying to run the job from jekins it fails and give the below error-

```
runners.TestRunner > Scenario: Extract the Report.classMethod FAILED
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException
```

Now the same works fine when I dont run that from the docker set up and do it from IntelliJ.

```
private WebDriver createSTAGEDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        switch (driverType) {
            case GridChrome :
                DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://xx.xx.xxx.xxxx:xxxxx/wd/hub"),cap);
                break;
```

Not able to figure out the problem.

Any help would be really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed,

Actual instead of IP in createSTAGEDriver function, I need to mention the name of the ip which was defined in my docker .yml file

```
version: '2'
services:
 hub:
   restart: always
   image: selenium/hub:3.14
   ports:
     - "4444:4444"
   networks:
     - "selenium-grid_default"
 firefox:
   restart: always
   image: selenium/node-firefox:3.5
   environment:
    - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
    - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=2
    - NODE_MAX_SESSION=2
   links:
    - "hub"
```

so basically instead of ip, I need to use this hub which is defined in links.